# sort a hash by using the values of keys

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like this:

```
a = { 29 => 3, 14 => 6, 13 => 2, 32 => 10 }
```

I want to sort this hash based on the values there, namely: 3,6,2,10

I can do `a.values.sort`

but it returns an array of just the sorted values. I want to sort the actual hash, so it should return a new hash (or ideally update the original hash with the sorted one) with all the same key-value pairs but sorted!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works on Ruby 1.9:

```
a = { 29 => 3, 14 => 6, 13 => 2, 32 => 10 }
p Hash[a.sort_by{|k,v| v}]
#=> {13=>2, 29=>3, 14=>6, 32=>10}
```

Comment: Cool, but he wants it sorted by value: `Hash[a.invert.sort].invert`

Comment: yes Abe Voelker.. that would be the answer! a.invert swtiches key-values to values-key and then sort them and then switch them back! awesome :D

Comment: steenslag... that's even better! :D thnx

Comment: `sort_by` is much better than `invert`ing twice.

Comment: Great, thanks!. Spent some time searching for the answer. Almost every answer still about Ruby 1.8.7, this is for 1.9 and above.

Answer (score 2):

A Hash in Ruby (pre-1.9) is unsorted. You can't 'return a new hash with the same key-value pairs sorted', because the Hash implementation simply does not keep the entries sorted. You have two options:

1. Use an instance of ActiveSupport::OrderedHash (from the active_support gem)
2. Use an array of sorted pairs to perform any actions that require sorted input. Convert back to a Hash by passing that array to a Hash constructor (Hash.new or Hash[])